# I cannot login to a user I just created in a PDB

Tags: oracle

Just installed Oracle 12c client and server for the first time (on same machine) so please bear with me as I'm quite new to this. It's in the multitenant mode.

So I went to the server's BIN directory and ran `sqlplus / as sysdba`. The SID is `TESTDB` and looking at `show pdbs;` I could see that there is one PDB called BPDB1. So I switched to it with `alter session set container = BPDB1` and opened it with `alter database open`. Now I created a user with `CREATE USER testtest IDENTIFIED BY password` which seemed to work.

After that, I thought I can login to the PDB from the client's BIN directory using `sqlplus testtest/password`. But that just gives me `ORA-01017 invalid username/password; login denied`.

I wonder if this is because the client doesn't know which PDB to connect to? How would I tell it this?

By the way, not sure if this is relevant but I tried setting `ORACLE_HOME` to the root of my client installation, but if that I got some other errors every time I try to start `sqlplus`. It hinted that `ORACLE_HOME` was set incorrectly, so I just unset that variable to continue.

Comment: To set (for local installations primarily) ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID you typically use ". oraenv" command. ORACLE_SID is not needed if you plan to connect via Listener (which is needed for PDB).

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting to root container by using `sqlplus testtest/password` where the user doesn't exist.

Instead, you can use [EZConnect](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/naming.htm#NETAG008) or you can create a TNS name to connect to the PDB.

**Example**:

**EZCONNECT**

```
[oracle@host ~]$ sqlplus testtest@hostname:port/bpdb1
```

**TNS Name**

First, find out the service name of the PDB, one of the methods has been shown below.

```
 [oracle@host ~]$ lsnrctl status listener_name

Service "orclpdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oracdbuat", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

In my case, it's `orclpdb`.
Go to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`.
Edit/Create `tnsnames.ora` file to add a similar entry as shown below.

```
ORCLPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orclpdb)
    )
  )
```

Now, I can connect to the PDB using the TNS name.

```
[oracle@host ~]$ sqlplus testtest@orclpdb
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. EZConnect sounds good. How do I know the port to put here, or is it required? I tried to omit it, but got error "ORA-12504". Not sure if this is related?

Comment: If you know the listener name, you can simply get it by querying it's status `[oracle@host ~]$ lsnrctl status`

Comment: I found the port using `tnsping TESTDB`, because the SID is `TESTDB`. It's port 1521. Strangely though, `tnsping` timed out. Does this mean the server is down? But service `OracleServiceTESTDB` is running. When I run your suggested EZConnect command, I just get `ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA`

Comment: and `lsnrctl status TESTDB` also times out and gives a similar response

Comment: TESTDB does not look like a typical listeenr name, try `lsnrctl status` or `lsnrctl status LISTENER` instead. tnsping will use 1521 as a default, it does not mean its the right port.

Comment: I have exactly this problem with Oracle 19. I can connect to the CDB and PDB1 just fine as user 'sys as sysdba'. However, I can't login as the user I created for my application (actually for my tests).  Helpfully I get the error message `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`, resetting the user password does not help. Does Oracle provide any readable log files (as in no hexdump in XML) that could give a hint why I can't log in?

Comment: I found out why I was unable to connect: I inadvertently wrote the `create user "username"` which made the user appear in `dba_users` in lowercase. Seems like it is impossible to login as a lowercase username. After recreating the user I could log in.

Answer (score -1):

A litte bit late on this thread, but maybe it will help others. I had a problem: i couldnt connect to Database after creating a new user. After struggling several hour, i got a "Success" on connection tab. Please try this options on SQL DEV Connection:

[image]

Also, i added that string on /network/admin as @atokpas mentioned before ( many thanks)

Also, i put on sqlnet.ora:
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT = 8

SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER = 8